# Suppose $y $ satisfies D.E. $dy/dx=y^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

Describe the behaviour of the following initial conditions:

$y (0)=0$,
$y (0)=0.01$,
$y (0)=-0.01$

Ans: if I solve for $y $ first I get: $y=1/(c-x) $

$y (0)=0$ gives me a vertical asymptote.

2nd and 3rd conditions give my constant 100 and -100 values respectively. Am I correct? Is that all I'm supposed to describe?

Comment: For $y(0)=0$ the conclusion isn't sound. (If $y(0)=0$, what does the ODE tell you about $y'(0)=0$?

Comment: That y=0 is constant point? I don't know